Outlook rules - see difference between meetings and appointments
When settings rules in Outlook for calendar events, how can I make a rule only apply to meetings and not appointments?
I am trying to make a rule that colors all meetings that are organized by me yellow, so that I know I need to lead it and possibly prepare. Setting up the filter was quite easy, but it also applies to appointments, which are always organized by me. How can I exclude appointments from the rule and have it apply to meetings only?

The obvious difference between a meeting and an appointment is that the meeting has attendees. Whereas, an appointment is an event that is scheduled at a specific time and does not involve other people.

When you create a meeting rule, select 'Apply rules to messages I receive' to select the criteria for the rule, such as sender, subject, or keyword.
When you create an appointment rule, select 'Apply rules to messages I send' to select the criteria for the rule, such as sender, subject, or keyword.

In addition, if you want to create a rule that applies only to meetings and not appointments, you can use the "Sent to" condition in the rule. This condition allows you to specify that the rule should only apply to messages that are sent to the calendar folder, which will exclude appointments that are not sent to the calendar folder.

"When you create an appointment rule, select 'Apply rules to messages I send'" Do appointments get send? I'm not quite sure what you mean.
"The obvious difference between a meeting and an appointment is that the meeting has attendees." That is a very good point. I used that for a workaround. I added the extra rule that 'required attendees' must be empty. It works very well. It should only fail when all attendees are set as optional, I don't think that will ever happen for me.
